# Open a file stored on a shared area from ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I need another time your help!

I'm working on a web application that stores some Office document (and any other kind of doc) on a remote shared area. I need to allow user to view the files available on shared area using my web application, how can I do that? Some years ago I solved this issue with Java / JSP opening into an output streaming the file, how can I do the same with ASP.NET and VB.NET? there is another way to solve my issue?

This is how I organized my application:

C:\Webapp -> Webapplication

\remoteserver\sharedfolder -> shared area

The owner of IIS process is the only user that can write / read the shared area.

I want thanks you all in advance!

bye,
Andrea

Comment: How do you mean view? List them? Provide links and downloads? Output to screen?

Comment: Output to screen or/and force download

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a good user experience, it might be better to **open the files in their native application** than to try to stream their content and display it on a web page. This assumes that the user has that native application on their machine. Particularly if this is a corporate application, you can probably assume that users have Microsoft Office, Notepad, and Adobe Reader.

The simplest way to open a file in its native application is to do this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("text.txt");
```

If you want to specify the application to use in opening the file:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("notepad.exe", "text.txt");
```

**To cause the file to be downloaded**, and have the user be prompted to save or open the file:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=testdoc.pdf");
Response.TransmitFile(@"e:\inet\www\docs\testdoc.pdf");
Response.End();
```

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck with your web app.